# Conditional column with a button in a grid javascript .net core

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, syncfusion

I'm trying to include a column with conditional in my Grid :

```
 $("#Grid").ejGrid({
                dataSource: ej.DataManager({
               .
    columns: [
             .
             .
      { headerText: 'Detail', template: '<a class="btn btn-info" href="/ServicesOrder/Detail/{{:ServicesOrderId}}">Detail</a>' },

{ headerText: 'Finish', template: '<a class="btn btn-sucess" >Finish</a>'
{ headerText: 'In progress', template: '<a class="btn btn-danger" >In progress</a>'
```

Indeed, i have a variable Rest (reste of payment) in my table ServicesOrder, my goal is to display one of the two columns :

```
if (rest==0) display --> { headerText: 'Finish', template: '<a class="btn btn-sucess" >Finish</a>'
Else display --> { headerText: 'In progress', template: '<a class="btn btn-danger" >In progress</a>'
```

Thank You in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your query, we understand that you need to render the anyone of the two buttons based on the value from the dataSource. We have achieved your requirement using columnTemplate feature and JS render if else condition.

Refer the below code example

```
  `<script type="text/x-jsrender" id="columnTemplate">
        {{if Verified}}
  <a class="btn btn-sucess">Finish</a>
        {{else}}
 <a class="btn btn-danger">In progress</a>
        {{/if}}   
    </script>
    <div id="Grid"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#Grid").ejGrid({
                // the datasource "window.employeeView" is referred from jsondata.min.js
                dataSource: window.gridData,
                allowPaging: true,
                pageSettings: { pageSize: 4 },
                columns: [
                    { field: "OrderID", headerText: "Order ID", isPrimaryKey: true, textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right, width: 90 },
                    { field: "CustomerID", headerText: "Customer ID", width: 150 },
                    { field: "EmployeeID", headerText: "Employee ID", textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right, width: 100 },
                    { field: "OrderDate", headerText: "Order Date", textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right, width: 100, format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" },
                    { field: "Freight", headerText: "Freight", textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right, format: "{0:C}" },
                    { field: "Verified", headerText: "Verified", width: 100 },
                    { headerText: "Employee Image", template: "#columnTemplate", textAlign: "center", width: 110 },
                ]
            });
        });
    </script>`
```

Refer the below sample

Sample: https://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/gvr2gkym

Refer the help documentation for your reference

https://help.syncfusion.com/js/grid/columns#column-template

https://www.jsviews.com/#iftag

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer:**
create a template as below :

```
    var detailTemplate = 
        "<a class='btn btn-info' rel='nofollow' rel='nofollow' href='/ServicesOrder/Detail/{{:ServicesOrderId}}'>Detail</a>"
        + ","
        + "<a class='btn {{:Rest==0 ?'btn-success':'btn-danger' }}'>"
        + "{{:Rest==0?'Finish':'In progress' }}"
        + "</a>";
```

**Demo :**

[image]

**Complete Code :**

```js
        var gridData = [
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-001', Note:'test note 1' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-002', Note:'test note 2' , Rest:1, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-003', Note:'test note 3' , Rest:3, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-004', Note:'test note 4' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-005', Note:'test note 5' , Rest:6, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-006', Note:'test note 6' , Rest:2, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-007', Note:'test note 7' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-008', Note:'test note 8' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-009', Note:'test note 9' , Rest:1, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-A1-010', Note:'test note 10' , Rest:2, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-001', Note:'test note 1' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-002', Note:'test note 2' , Rest:1, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-003', Note:'test note 3' , Rest:3, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-004', Note:'test note 4' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-005', Note:'test note 5' , Rest:6, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-006', Note:'test note 6' , Rest:2, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-007', Note:'test note 7' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-008', Note:'test note 8' , Rest:0, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-009', Note:'test note 9' , Rest:1, },
            {ServicesOrderId: 'SO-B1-010', Note:'test note 10' , Rest:2, },
        ];

    var detailTemplate = 
        "<a class='btn btn-info' rel='nofollow' rel='nofollow' href='/ServicesOrder/Detail/{{:ServicesOrderId}}'>Detail</a>"
        + ","
        + "<a class='btn {{:Rest==0 ?'btn-success':'btn-danger' }}'>"
        + "{{:Rest==0?'Finish':'In progress' }}"
        + "</a>";

    $("#Grid").ejGrid({            
        dataSource: window.gridData,
        allowPaging: true,  
        
        columns: [
            { field: "ServicesOrderId", isPrimaryKey: true, headerText: "Order ID" , textAlign: ej.TextAlign.Right, width: 90  },
            { field: "Note", headerText: 'Note', width: 90 },
            { 
                headerText: 'Detail', 
                template:  detailTemplate,
            },
        ] 
    });
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/13.2.0.34/js/web/flat-azure/ej.web.all.min.css" />
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/js/assets/external/jsrender.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.syncfusion.com/13.2.0.34/js/web/ej.web.all.min.js"> </script>
    
    <div style="padding:10px">
        <div id="Grid"></div>
    </div>
```